# SQL function to return the number or records in a given table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a simple function in SQL that takes a table name as input
and return the number of records for that table.

How can I create such a 'dynamic' function?

Comment: @DStanley the question is for SQL Server

Comment: You cannot create a function to do this in SQL Server (at least not mere mortals) because SQL Server functions cannot use dynamic SQL.  You could do this with a stored procedure, but that is not your question.

Comment: If you don't actually need the exact number, you could use: `SELECT SUM(rows) FROM sys.partitions WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTable') AND index_id IN (0,1);`. It's very fast and no need for dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh but you do NOT have to use dynamic sql for something like this. You can instead use the table partitions.

This should work for you. The one caveate is that it is possible this may not always be 100% accurate but I have never seen it not be correct. According to the documentation it is the "approximate number of rows in the partition".

```
create function GetTableRowCount
(
    @TableName sysname
) returns table as return
    SELECT SUM(row_count) AS MyRowCount
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
    GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id);
```

This is even an inline table valued function instead of more common scalar function.